# I need to find out the location of the error in the code by eclipse Imarker in jdt plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

[image: The marker Properties]

I need to get In folder details, location, on element details.

```
IResource project=null;
try {
    problems=workspace.getRoot().findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, depth);

    HttpClientExample hc=   new HttpClientExample();

    for (int i = 0; i < problems.length; i++) {
        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "FindMakers",

    "Hello,"+problems[i].getAttribute(IMarker.LOCATION)); 

}
```

but in folder details haven't attribute for the detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the resource containing the marker using:

```
IMarker marker = .... the marker

IResource resource = marker.getResource();
```

The `IResource` will usually be a file:

```
if (resource instanceof IFile) {

    IFile file = (IFile)resource;

    // The file name
    String name = file.getName();  

    IContainer folder = file.getParent();

    // The folder name
    String folderPath = folder.getFullPath().toString();
}
```

The line number is given by

```
marker.getAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER);
```

Some markers may just have character start / end positions given by:

```
marker.getAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START);
marker.getAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END);
```

Comment: Seems like resource instanceof IFile is false

Comment: resource.getLocation().toString() give thi file location thank you bro